# GCD function event handler for DispatchSource in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

In Objective-C, you could specify the event handler for a dispatch source as either a block or a function. From Apple's [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/GCDWorkQueues/GCDWorkQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH103-SW1):

> Function-based event handlers take a single context pointer,
>   containing the dispatch source object, and return no value.
>   Block-based event handlers take no parameters and have no return
>   value.

In Swift 3, is it still possible to use a function as an event handler? I only see how to use a block. I need access to the source in my handler and I need to define my handler separately from where the source is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
class Foo {
    var eventHandler: (DispatchSourceRead) -> Void
    init(handler: @escaping (DispatchSourceRead) -> Void) {
        eventHandler = handler
    }
}

let foo = Foo() { source in
    print("got event from source")
}

let source = DispatchSource.makeReadSource(fileDescriptor: 0)
source.setEventHandler {
    foo.eventHandler(source)
}
```

Comment: You are using the block event handler, but you've written it so as to capture the source? Is that right? Could you have also done something like: `let foo: (DispatchSourceRead) -> Void = { source in print("hi \(source)") }` and then `source.setEventHandler { foo(source) }`? In other words, why do you need `class Foo`?

Comment: You don't need the class. That was my first thought as to why you needed it defined away from the source. To prevent the capture, you can add a capture list to the event handler that uses a weak reference to source.